# React : how to pass a state from child to parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'd like to pass `filteredData` in the child Component **PokemonSearchBar.jsx** so that I can use it in the parent component **PokemonList.jsx** to map only filtered Pokemon. In other words, when I do a search, the search component will compare the characters from the `e.target.value` of my input to the ones of the `data` array (filled with all the Pokemon names), which is passed as a prop from the parent component **PokemonList.jsx**. If there are some characters in common between the `e.target.value` and the `data` array, the `filteredData` will receive only the Pokemon with characters in common with `e.target.value` from the input.

Is there any way that I can pass the `filteredData` state to the parent component as a prop ?

Here is the child component **PokemonSearchBar.jsx**:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import './PokemonSearchBar.css';

import SearchIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Search';
import CloseIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Close';

export default function PokemonSearchBar({ placeholder, data }) {
    const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState([]);
    const [wordEntered, setWordEntered] = useState("");

    const handleFilter = (e) => {
        const searchWord = e.target.value;
        setWordEntered(searchWord);
        const newFilter = data.filter(value => {
            return (value.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchWord.toLowerCase()));
        });
        
        if(searchWord === "") {
            setFilteredData([]);
        } else {
            setFilteredData(newFilter);
        }
    }

    const clearInput = (e) => {
        setWordEntered("");
        setFilteredData([]);
    }

  return (
    <div className='search'>
        <div className="row" style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            <div className="col-3"></div>
            <div className="col-6">
                <div className="searchInputs" style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control rounded" placeholder={placeholder} onChange={handleFilter} value={wordEntered} />
                    {filteredData.length === 0 ? <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary"><SearchIcon /></button> : <button type="button" className="btn btn-warning"><CloseIcon onClick={clearInput} /></button>}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="col-3"></div>
        </div>
        {filteredData.length !== 0 &&
            <div className="dataResult mx-auto" style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                <ul>
                    {filteredData.slice(0, 15).map((pokemon) => {
                        return (<li style={{ listStyleType: 'none', textDecoration: 'none'}} className="dataItem"><Link to="/" className="a" style={{ textDecoration: 'none', color: 'black' }}>{pokemon.name}</Link></li>)
                    })}
                </ul>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Here is the parent component **PokemonList.jsx**:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import ReactPaginate from 'react-paginate';

import PokemonCard from './PokemonCard';
import PokemonSearchBar from './PokemonSearchBar';


export default class PokemonList extends Component {
    state = {
        url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=100000&offset=0",
        pokemon: [], // on créé un objet (qui va devenir un tableau) pokemon null c'est où on va enregistrer le json
        pageNumber: 0,
        pokemonsPerPage: 16
    };

    async componentDidMount() {
        const res = await axios.get(this.state.url); // on attend de récupérer les pokemon avant d'exectuer la suite de la fonction
        console.log(res.data['results']);
        this.setState({pokemon: res.data['results']}); // on passe un objet dans le state et on affecte à pokemon le tableau résultats de la data de l'url
        // setState re-render seulement les éléments qu'il faut re-rendre
    };

    render() {
        console.log(this.state.pokemon);

        const pagesVisited = this.state.pageNumber * this.state.pokemonsPerPage;

        const displayUsers = this.state.pokemon
            .slice(pagesVisited, pagesVisited + this.state.pokemonsPerPage)
            .map((pokemon) => {
                return (
                    <PokemonCard 
                        key={pokemon.name} // on utilise le props name comme clé unique car chaque nom de pokemon est unique
                        name={pokemon.name} // c'est le props name dans le pokemonCard
                        url={pokemon.url} // c'est le props url dans le pokemonCard
                    /> // on génère autant de cartes qu'il y a de pokemons dans le tableau results
                )
            });

        const pageCount = Math.ceil(this.state.pokemon.length / this.state.pokemonsPerPage); // ceil() permet d'arrondir au supérieur

        const changePage = ({selected}) => {
            this.setState({pageNumber: selected})
        }

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <PokemonSearchBar  data={this.state.pokemon} placeholder="Enter a Pokemon name" />
                <br />
                {this.state.pokemon ? ( // s'il y a quelquechose dans le state
                    <div className='row'>
                        {displayUsers}
                        <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                            <ReactPaginate 
                                previousLabel={"previous"}
                                nextLabel={"Next"}
                                pageCount={pageCount}
                                onPageChange={changePage}
                                containerClassName={"paginationButtons"}
                                previousLinkClassName={"previousButton"}
                                nextLinkClassName={"nextButton"}
                                disabledClassName={"paginationDisabled"}
                                activeClassName={"paginationActive"}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ) : (<h2>Loading Pokemon</h2>)} 
                {/* S'il n'y a rien dans le state afficher que le pokemon est en train de charger */}
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In React there are essentially 3 ways to send data up:

1. Via callback passed as a prop;
2. Via Store (Redux or Context API, or other)
3. Via native custom Javascript events

Your use-case can be implemented via prop:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import './PokemonSearchBar.css';

import SearchIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Search';
import CloseIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Close';

export default function PokemonSearchBar({ placeholder, data, onDataFiltered }) {
    const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState([]);
    const [wordEntered, setWordEntered] = useState("");

    const handleFilter = (e) => {
        const searchWord = e.target.value;
        setWordEntered(searchWord);
        const newFilter = data.filter(value => {
            return (value.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchWord.toLowerCase()));
        });
        
        if(searchWord === "") {
            setFilteredData([]);
            onDataFiltered([])
        } else {
            setFilteredData(newFilter);
            onDataFiltered(newFilter)
        }
    }

    const clearInput = (e) => {
        setWordEntered("");
        setFilteredData([]);
    }

  return (
    <div className='search'>
        <div className="row" style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            <div className="col-3"></div>
            <div className="col-6">
                <div className="searchInputs" style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control rounded" placeholder={placeholder} onChange={handleFilter} value={wordEntered} />
                    {filteredData.length === 0 ? <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary"><SearchIcon /></button> : <button type="button" className="btn btn-warning"><CloseIcon onClick={clearInput} /></button>}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="col-3"></div>
        </div>
        {filteredData.length !== 0 &&
            <div className="dataResult mx-auto" style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                <ul>
                    {filteredData.slice(0, 15).map((pokemon) => {
                        return (<li style={{ listStyleType: 'none', textDecoration: 'none'}} className="dataItem"><Link to="/" className="a" style={{ textDecoration: 'none', color: 'black' }}>{pokemon.name}</Link></li>)
                    })}
                </ul>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
  )
}
```

You will then declare it like this:

```
 <PokemonSearchBar
    data={this.state.pokemon}
    placeholder="Enter a Pokemon name"
    onDataFiltered={(newData) => {
       console.log("do something with the new data", newData);
    }}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering quickly. When I do what you did, I get an error when I type a letter in the input: **onDataFiltered is not a function** so I guess you can't do `if(searchWord === "") { setFilteredData([]); onDataFiltered([]); } else { setFilteredData(newFilter); onDataFiltered(newFilter); }`

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: I did a this in the parent component **PokemonList.jsx** `const {onDataFiltered} = this.props;`, `console.log(onDataFiltered);`

Comment: The error is: **TypeError: onDataFiltered is not a function**

Comment: My bad, I replaced the `console.log("do something with the new data", newData);` with `this.setState({newData})` (I created `newData: []` in the state) and I replaced `const displayUsers = this.state.pokemon` with `const displayUsers = this.state.newData` and It worked.

Comment: @AmauryGimonnet, awesome, good luck.